# Add a time stop after each loop execution

Tags: php

As you can see I have a script that sends emails by using mail function. The script works just fine, but I would like to add "time stop" after each while loop execution. For example lets say I would like to add 2 sec stop after each execution, the loop would work in a way: execute (wait 2 sec) execute (wait 2 sec) execute (wait 2 sec)...
So at final, the script would work in a way: Send email (wait 2 sec) Send another email (wait 2 sec)...

I have tried to search the internet for similar problem, but I could not find anything that would help.

Is something like this even possible to do?

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my script for everyone who would like to review it.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("Can not connect to DB");
mysqli_select_db($con,"some_db")or die("Can not select DB");
$sql= "SET time_zone = '+00:00'; SELECT * FROM tbt WHERE DAY(date) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE());";
if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $sql)) {
    do {

        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $to = $row["email"];
                $subject = 'Something';
                $message = 'Hello';
                $headers = 'From:noreply@something.net' . "\r\n";
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
               /* I suppose that stop would go here */
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while (mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [sleep(2)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php);

But be careful. php scripts usually have. [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) setting of a minute or two, and the time you sleep counts against that.

sendgrid.com is an emailing service with a free service tier. They don't rate limit your outgoing emails, rather they give you monthly and maybe daily message limits unless you pay them. That might be a better solution to your problem than sleeps in php scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[Sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) sounds like what you're looking for.

```php
while(false === $whatever) {
   sleep(2); // halt execution for 2 seconds.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much